# Interior, closure of sets in cofinite topology

Tags: general-topology

Given cofinite topology find the interior and closure of finite and infinite set.

I have read few answer on this topic but I would like to chat about this more.

For example if topological space is (R, T) (where T is the given topology) Is R closed? Meaning $R^c = R$

Comment: What is your question? I don’t understand what you wrote.

Comment: In any topological space, the set consisting of the entire space is always both open and closed because, by definition, a topology must contain both the set consisting of the entire space and also the empty set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closed sets in a cofinite topology are exactly the finite sets and the space itself. So any finite set is already closed. For any infinite set, the only closed set it is contained in is the space itself, so its closure must be the entire space.

Similarly, the only open sets are the empty set and the cofinite set. $x$ is in the interior of $A$ iff there is an open set $B$ such that $x⋹B⊆A$. If $A$ is not cofinite, it doesn't contain any cofinite sets, so this isn't tre for any $x$. Hence it has an empty interior. If $A$ is cofinite, it is open, so its interior is itself.